# Vector bundle of rank 2 and with a section don't vanish anywhere

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I have a vector bundle of rank 2 which have a vanish nowhere section. So, this is sufficciently to conclude that it is trivial?

I know that a vector bundle of rank n is trivial if and only if it has n sections linerly independent. But with this property I can't proove what I asumed above.

Are conditions mentioned above enough? I will appreciatte any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not enough. Let $E\to X$ be your vector bundle, and $s:X\to E$ your section.

Then the bundle that has fibers $E_x/Vect(s(x))$ is a line bundle over $X$ and it would be trivial if $E$ were, but of course some spaces have nontrivial line bundles.

Let $L\to X$ be a nontrivial line bundle, then the Whitney sum of $L$ and a trivial line bundle over $X$ is nontrivial, has rank $2$, but a continuous nowhere vanishing section (any such section coming from the trivial summand)

(as pointed out by Qiaochu in the comments, this last bit uses that we're in the line+line situation, otherwise it need not be true : there are nontrivial stably trivial bundles)

Comment: It requires a teensy argument that the sum of a trivial and nontrivial line bundle must be nontrivial (e.g. a calculation of the SW classes or the exterior square) - worth noting that it’s false that the sum of a trivial and nontrivial vector bundle must be nontrivial! (E.g. the tangent bundle of $S^2$ plus a trivial line is trivial.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : you're right of course (otherwise stably trivial vector bundles would be trivial). But in this situation I think there are also elementary solutions (e.g. using an inner product on the sum bundle)

Comment: I think computing the exterior square is pretty elementary! We have $\Lambda^n(L_1 \oplus \dots L_n) = L_1 \otimes \dots L_n$ where the $L_i$ are lines so the conclusion is that a direct sum of lines is nontrivial as long as the tensor product is. Of course this is equivalent to computing $w_1$ but this argument generalizes to e.g. finitely generated projective modules over a commutative ring too.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Ah you're completely right, sorry I don't know what I was thinking !

Comment: @Maxime Ramzi and Qiaochu Yuan, thank you for yours answers! So, from Qiaochu Yuan's comment, do I need to know some aditional information of the SW classes or exterior square of a bundle?, I don't know the SW classes but I know the Chern Classes, these are null; Is this helpful to determined that the bundle is trivial?